# H.264 Video Encoding

Tags: video-processing, video-encoding

I'm working on a video encoding component that suppose to Transcode a stream from Resolution X to Resolution Y and stream it over the network (down scaling).
I'm getting an encoded stream which I need to decode, rescale and encode again.

What I'm thinking of doing in order to reduce the CPU is to decode only the key-frames and then do the re-scale and encoding.

Will it be more beneficial from CPU-wise perspective to also encode only to key-frames as well? meaning, each decoded key-frame will be encoded to key-frame.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good (patentable) idea! However, most codec doesn't really support this right now. Give a sequence, resolution of all frames must be same. Resolution of key frame cannot be different from that of other frames. Partly this is also needed because of gamuts of motion compensation algorithms involved in construction of P and B frames from I and P frames. (a.k.a IDR frames in H.264).

In my knowledge H.264 also doesn't support this as well. Will be happy to know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand this question, if you decode,rescale and encode only the keyframes only 1 in 30(assuming key frame interval is 30) will be rescaled. Is that what you want? that is 3.3% of stream. What purpose would this serve? Key frames in video compression mean Intra/IDR frames.